# Workspaces applications

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, workspaces, ubuntu-dock

I am trying to take advantage of workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04. I was used to the Windows 10 equivalent (don't blame me) and I am trying to replicate a feature that it's pretty useful to me.

On the application bar (Ubuntu dock) I see all the open applications for all the workspaces. Is there a way to see the open applications **only** for the current workspace? I can do this for the applications I cycle through using <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> with an option in `dconf-editor`, but it doesn't affect the applications I see in the bar